# Find $f$ and $g$ that are both $C^1$ with $f(y)=g(y)=0$ and $f'(y)= a g'(y) \neq 0$, but $\lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ DNE.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

> Find $f$ and $g$ that are both $C^1$ with $f(y)=g(y)=0$ and $f'(y)= a g'(y) \neq 0$, where $a\in\mathbb{R}$ but $\lim_{x\to y} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ DNE.

I know that for this to be true we must have that $f,g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, where $n \neq 1$.

Comment: This was poorly written originally, and although you've made it clearer, it's still not well stated. You should make it clear where $f,g$ are defined at the very beginning, and what $f'(y),g'(y)$ mean. When you are sloppy like this, you can confuse even very able mathematicians, such as David Ullrich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's work in $\mathbb R^2.$ Take $y=(0,0).$ Set

$$f(x_1,x_2) = x_1 +x_1^2,\,\, g(x_1,x_2) = x_1 +x_2^2.$$

We have the hypotheses met with $\nabla f(0,0) = (1,0)=\nabla g(0,0),$ and $a=1.$

Note $f(0,t)/g(0,t) = 0/t^2 \to 0$ as $t\to 0,$ while $f(t,0)/g(t,0) \to 1$ as $t\to 0.$ Thus $\lim f(x)/g(x)$ fails to exist as $x\to (0,0).$

Comment: In fact it's worse than that -- there are points near the origin where $g=0$, so $f/g$ does not exist, let alone the limit of $f/g$... (In fact $n>1$, $g(0)=0$, $g'(0)\ne0$ _implies_ that there are points near the origin where $g$ vanishes; so we don't need to construct a counterexample, anything satisfying the hypotheses is a counterexample!)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm aware of the "$f/g$ does not exist" argument. I made it myself in my early days here. But around MSE this argument is mostly not accepted, as it is usually assumed $x\to (0,0)$ within a neighborhood minus the zero set of $g.$

Answer (score 0):

Two possibly interesting new bits: (i) for real-valued functions on $\Bbb R^n$ we don't need to construct a counterexample, in fact there are no non-counterexamples. (ii) There *is* a sort of L'Hopital for functions from $\Bbb R^n$ to itself.

First,

> > If $n>1$, $f,g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$, $g(0)=0$, $g'(0)$ exists and $g'(0)\ne0$ then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)/g(x)$ does not exist.

This is clear from

> > If $g$ is as above and $\delta>0$ then there exists $x$ with $0<|x|<\delta$ and $g(x)=0$.

Proof: Let $A=\{0<|x|<\delta\}$. Since $g'(0)\ne0$ there exist $x,y\in A$ with $g(x)<0$ and $g(y)>0$. The fact that $n>1$ shows that $A$ is connected, and so $g$ vanishes at some point of $A$.

Second: Of course the very notion of L'Hopital for $f,g:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ seems absurd, since there's no such thing as $f/g$. But we can rephrase things to avoid division: For real-valued functions saying $f/g\to\alpha$ is the same as saying $$f-\alpha g=o(g).$$

It turns out that the condition $g'(0)\ne0$ is not right; what's relevant is whether $g'(0)$ is *invertible*:

> > Suppose $f,g:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$, $f(0)=g(0)=0$, $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at the origin, $g'(0)$ is invertible and $f'(0)=\alpha g'(0)$. Then $f(x)-\alpha g(x)=o(g(x))$ as $x\to0$.

Proof: Say $A=g'(0)$, so we have $$g(x)=Ax+o(x)$$and$$f(x)=\alpha Ax+o(x).$$Hence $$f(x)-\alpha g(x)=o(x)\quad(x\to0).$$

But since $A$ is invertible there exist $c>0$ and $\delta>0$ with $$|g(x)|\ge c|x|\quad(|x|<\delta).$$So, perhaps a bit iinformally, $$o(x)=o(g(x)).$$

**Original**, where I assumed we were talking about functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$:

No, L'Hopital's rule does not fail, not ever. It's a *theorem*. The *conclusion* may fail, *if* the hypotheses are not satisfied.

Anyway, it's easy to see that the example you ask for cannot exist. In fact

> > If $f(y)=g(y)=0$, $f'(y)$ and $g'(y)$ exist, and $g'(y)\ne0$ then $f(x)/g(x)\to f'(y)/g'(y)$ as $x\to y$.

This is trivial from the definition of the derivative. Note first that since $g'(y)\ne0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $g(x)\ne0$ for $0<|x-y|<\delta$. For such $x$ we have $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{(f(x)-f(y))/(x-y)}{(g(x)-g(y))/(x-y)}\to \frac{f'(y)}{g'(y)}\quad(x\to y).$$

Comment: L'hoptials Rule is a theorem for functions with domain and codomain, $\mathbb{R}$. I do not believe it generalizes over to higher dimensions. I believe an example must exist, particularly since this is an exercise from the aforementioned textbook, Stromberg. I agree that for functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ L'Hoptials rule will always work given the hypotheses are satisfied. Sorry if my question was not clear initially.

Comment: You believe an example must exist. An example of _what_, exactly? This is an exercise -_what_ is an exercise? (I know that the exercise does not ask for the example you asked for...)

Comment: Find an $f$ and $g$ such that $f,g:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (see my last sentence), which are both $C^1$ with $f(y) = g(y) = 0$, and $f'(y) = ag'(y) \neq 0$, where $\lim_{x\to y} f(x)/g(x)$ does not exist.

No example exists with $n=m=1$.

Comment: I edited the question for it to be more straight-forward and took out the authors example.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. There's no such thing as $f(x)/g(x)$ in that setting; you can't divide vectors. What does the exercise _really_ ask for? Perhaps "editing" the question was a bad idea - what does the original ask, exactly?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $f,g$ are intended to be real valued, although the OP didn't make that clear.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks. (Actually I figured that our, wasn't going to admit it until he said so...)